# Different sizes of Micro ATX

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, micro-atx

A Case says it allows for MicroATX, with dimensions 9.6in x 9.6in
but a motherboard is MicroATX, with the dimensions 9.6in x 8.8in. Will the motherboard still  work with the case? as they are both MicroATX

Also is a different PSU needed for a microATX motherboard than an ATX one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The max size of a MicroATX motherboard is 9.6in x 9.6in but they can be much smaller (6.75 in x 6.75 in according [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microatx)).

They use the same power supply connectors as the regular ATX motherboards.

Comment: so they are both compatible?

Comment: Yes, they are. Give us the brand and model of the case and the motherboard if you want to be 200% sure.

Comment: http://www.asrock.com/mb/overview.asp?Model=P55M%20Pro&s=1156

ASRock P55M Pro and 
http://www.akasa.com.tw/update.php?tpl=product/product.detail.tpl&no=181&type=Chassis&type_sub=Mid%20ATX&model=AK-BKXNE-01

Akasa Freedom Xone

Answer (score 3):

There's a little site called http://www.formfactors.org/ that covers this. A couple screw holes are optional, the actual width is variable up to a limit based on the number of slots provided. The smaller board will mount and fit in the 9.6 x 9.6 space in the case.